# How to plot area type highchart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dota2pro/m6t93sLy/4/) **Code reproduction**,

I am using Highcharts to plot an area graph, how do I do the below ?

1. I need to move the y-axis labels to the right
2. Plot Area chart of 3 colors `['#762232', '#EFCA32', '#007788']` with their respective values.

Expected Output [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set `yAxis.opposite` to `true`.
2. Add two more series and use `tickPositioner` to show thier last values as labels.

   ```
    yAxis: {
        opposite: true,
        showFirstLabel: false,
        showLastLabel: false,
        tickPositioner: function() {
            var prevTickPos = this.tickPositions,
                tickPositions = [prevTickPos[0], prevTickPos[prevTickPos.length - 1]],
                series = this.chart.series;

            series.forEach(function(s) {
                tickPositions.push(s.processedYData[s.processedYData.length - 1]);
            });

            tickPositions.sort(function(a, b) {
                return a - b;
            });

            return tickPositions;
        },
        ...
    }
   ```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gk1t6cp2/

**API Refernce:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.opposite

Comment: Thanks, could you also take a look at this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67059053/how-to-show-an-empty-chart-in-beginning-and-populate-values-on-button-click