# How to show an empty chart in beginning and populate values on button click

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have code from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66802971/how-to-plot-area-type-highchart). I want to populate the chart on click of a button instead of initializing it and provide only 3 values e.g.`22286,12286,9286` ( these values would be dynamic) and plot the chart with the same appearance (i.e. 3 colors chart) as of the snippet

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  colors: ['#762232', '#EFCA32', '#007788'],
  title: {
    text: '',
  },
  chart: {
    type: 'area',
    backgroundColor: null,
    // spacingRight: 5,
    spacingTop: 5,
    spacingBottom: 5,
    style: {
      fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif',
    },
    plotBorderWidth: 1,
    plotBorderColor: '#ccc',
  },

  xAxis: {
    gridZIndex: 4,
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    tickInterval: 1,
    tickWidth: 0,
    alignTicks: true,
    gridLineColor: '#762232',
    minPadding: 0,
    maxPadding: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Years Invested',
    },
    labels: {
      enabled: true,
    },
  },

  yAxis: {
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    opposite: true,
    title: {
      text: 'Hypothetical Value',
    },
    showFirstLabel: false,
    showLastLabel: false,
    tickPositioner: function() {
      var prevTickPos = this.tickPositions,
        tickPositions = [prevTickPos[0], prevTickPos[prevTickPos.length - 1]],
        series = this.chart.series;

      series.forEach(function(s) {
        tickPositions.push(s.processedYData[s.processedYData.length - 1]);
      });

      tickPositions.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a - b;
      });

      return tickPositions;
    },
    labels: {
      enabled: true,
      align: "right",
      reserveSpace: true,
    },
  },
  tooltip: {
    enabled: !1,
  },
  plotOptions: {
    area: {
      pointStart: 0,
      stacking: false,
      lineColor: '#762232',
      lineWidth: 1,
      fillOpacity: 1,
      dataLabels: {
        crop: !1,
        color: '#762232',
        align: 'right',
        y: 5,
      },
      marker: {
        enabled: !1,
        symbol: 'circle',
        radius: 1,
        states: {
          hover: {
            enabled: !1,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },

  series: [{
    data: [4457, 13371, 22286]
  }, {
    data: [2457, 9371, 12286]
  }, {
    data: [1457, 5371, 9286]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>

</figure>

<button>Populate Chart</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to create series with empty data array and use `chart.update` method to add data. Example:

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    ...,
    series: [{
        data: []
    }, {
        data: []
    }, {
        data: []
    }]
});

document.getElementById('chartInit').addEventListener('click', function(){
    chart.update({
        series: [{
            data: [4457, 13371, 22286]
        }, {
            data: [2457, 9371, 12286]
        }, {
            data: [1457, 5371, 9286]
        }]
    });
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8pL6hr3w/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update