# How to make highchart span over whole x-axis?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have code from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67059053/how-to-show-an-empty-chart-in-beginning-and-populate-values-on-button-click), when I increase the number of years,

```
    xAxis: {
        ....
        min: 0,
        max: 3, // This is dynamic
```

The chart gets limited only to 0,1 years. how can I make the chart spans end to end so that it looks like this

Edit: the problem is that x-axis "years invested" comes from a variable and the no. of years changes e.g. in this problem it is 3, so the chart needs to go expand all the way from 0 to 3 (left to right) on the x-axis as is in the screenshot, I used max to show 3 years on x-axis, and the 3 values I will plot on y-axis will come from variables as well, in this e.g. its '22286,12286,9286' i will have only these 3 values and the graph will start from 0. so I cannot put any other arbitrary value in the series

[image]

```js
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  colors: ['#762232', '#EFCA32', '#007788'],
  title: {
    text: '',
  },
  chart: {
    type: 'area',
    backgroundColor: null,
    // spacingRight: 5,
    spacingTop: 5,
    spacingBottom: 5,
    style: {
      fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif',
    },
    plotBorderWidth: 1,
    plotBorderColor: '#ccc',
  },

  xAxis: {
    gridZIndex: 4,
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    tickInterval: 1,
    tickWidth: 0,
    alignTicks: true,
    gridLineColor: '#762232',
    minPadding: 0,
    maxPadding: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 3,
    title: {
      text: 'Years Invested',
    },
    labels: {
      enabled: true,
    },
  },

  yAxis: {
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    opposite: true,
    title: {
      text: 'Hypothetical Value',
    },
    showFirstLabel: false,
    showLastLabel: false,
    tickPositioner: function() {
      var prevTickPos = this.tickPositions,
        tickPositions = [prevTickPos[0], prevTickPos[prevTickPos.length - 1]],
        series = this.chart.series;

      series.forEach(function(s) {
        tickPositions.push(s.processedYData[s.processedYData.length - 1]);
      });

      tickPositions.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a - b;
      });

      return tickPositions;
    },
    labels: {
      enabled: true,
      align: "right",
      reserveSpace: true,
    },
  },
  tooltip: {
    enabled: !1,
  },
  plotOptions: {
    area: {
      pointStart: 0,
      stacking: false,
      lineColor: '#762232',
      lineWidth: 1,
      fillOpacity: 1,
      dataLabels: {
        crop: !1,
        color: '#762232',
        align: 'right',
        y: 5,
      },
      marker: {
        enabled: !1,
        symbol: 'circle',
        radius: 1,
        states: {
          hover: {
            enabled: !1,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },

  series: [{
    data: []
  }, {
    data: []
  }, {
    data: []
  }]
});

document.getElementById('chartInit').addEventListener('click', function() {
  chart.update({
    series: [{
      data: [0, 22286]
    }, {
      data: [0, 12286]
    }, {
      data: [0, 9286]
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<button id="chartInit">Init chart</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @dota2pro, Could you explain the problem in more details? It seems that you don't need to use `min` and `max` properties.

Comment: @ppotaczek the problem is that x-axis "years invested" comes from a variable and the no. of years changes e.g. in this problem it is 3, so the chart needs to go expand all the way from 0 to 3 (left to right) on the x-axis as is in the screenshot, I used max to show 3 years on x-axis, and the 3 values I will plot on y-axis will come from  variables as well, in this e.g. its '22286,12286,9286' i will have only these 3 values and the graph will start from 0. so I cannot put any other arbitrary value in the series

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't fully understand. If you don't use `min`/`max`, the plot will span over whole x-axis, example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3k5seq0b/

Comment: @ppotaczek the issue with your jsfiddle is that you have put in arbitrary values for series. in your example e.g. I just have last values plotted on y -axis i.e. `33333,22222,10000`, so the chart has to start from 0 and go to these values, I don't have other values to fill in the series. But I still have to show the chart span over 3 ( or any no. of years , x-axis)
  `  series: [{
   data: [4457, 13371, 22286, 33333, 33333]
  }, {
   data: [2457, 9371, 12286, 22222, 22222]
  }, {
   data: [1457, 5371, 9286, 10000, 10000]
  }]`

Comment: Ok, so for example here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x9yvbtu8/ you want to show the series on the whole x-axis?

Comment: Modified you jsfiddle a little bit, https://jsfiddle.net/dota2pro/75d4r8vs/ , i want to  show the series on the whole x-axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define data in `[x, y]` format and use `yearsInvested` variable as a value of the second point.

```
  const yearsInvested = 10;

  chart.update({
    series: [{
      data: [
        [0, 0],
        [yearsInvested, 22286]
      ]
    }, {
      data: [
        [0, 0],
        [yearsInvested, 12286]
      ]
    }, {
      data: [
        [0, 0],
        [yearsInvested, 9286]
      ]
    }]
  });
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zun7cdge/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.data

Comment: Is it possible to keep y-axis title on the left, while still having y-axis labels on the right, as `Hypothetical Value` is placed in the screenshot, but $ values are on the right, ? (this is a screenshot from Highchart version 6.1.1 )

Comment: Hi @dota2pro, Yes, you need to create another y-axis, only with title. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s43b0Lfa/